# Google Play Games Services Skill Based Matchmaking Algorithm

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I've been looking into using the Google Play Services multiplayer functionality for a game and I was wondering if it would be possible to implement a matchmaking system like HoN/LoL/DotA2 (and plenty of other games) where each player has a skill rating and gets matched into games with players of similar skill, and if they wait too long then they can get matched against players further away from their skill level.

The only thing I've come across that gives you control over the Google Play matchmaking algorithm is the ability to specify an exclusive bitmask, but I don't see how that can be used to achieve what I want.

Does anyone know of a way to implement a dynamic skill based matchmaking algorithm in Google's system, or an alternative system that I could use (preferably free)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [setVariant(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.Builder.html#setVariant(int)) method when building the room. That way you only need to pass skill level to the method and only players on the same level will get matched up.

Although I don't think Google Play Games Services provide a way to expand the set of players the current player can get matched up against.

Comment: Thanks. That would at least let me implement a simple tier system which I wouldn't be able to do with the exclusive bitmask. It'd also let me have players queue for different game modes or maps they want to play.